# Can I check if a file exists with JS without triggering a 404 warning?

Tags: javascript

This function

```
export default function(url) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open("HEAD", url, false);
  http.send();
  return http.status != 404;
}
```

triggers a red 404 warning in the console when the file doesn't exist and while it works fine, I like to keep the console clean of errors. Is this unavoidable?

Comment: Nop, it is not.

Comment: Have you tried `try/catch`?

Comment: @Variable Oh I wonder if that'll work with a 404 warning as opposed to an error. Actually I've never used try catch because I've heard it labeled as sort of bad code in certain contexts so I didnt even think of it.